# jQuery toggle() - adding and removing class for active element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Currently, I am using this snippet:

```
$('.element-block').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".key-element").toggle();

    $('.background-area').removeClass("active_bg");
    $(this).parent('.background-area').addClass("active_bg");
});
```

I have list of `DIV` elements. In this block, when I click on the `.element-block`, the `jQuery` function **toggle()** displays needed area, if I click again, **toggle** hide it and also I am adding the background color to this area.

This is working well, for example: I click the A `.block-element` - data are appeared + background color changed. Then I click the B `.block-element` - data are appeared + background color changed. Cool.

But if I click on the A `.block-element` - data are appeared + background color changed and then if I click again the A `.block-element` - data will be hidden, but the background color **is not changed**.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle?

Comment: can u give the css and html??

Comment: You are adding the "active_bg" class to one element, but appear to be removing it from a different element. Can you post some example html to illustrate the structure?

Comment: Guys, thank you for your afford and the willingness to help me, `Felix`'s solution did the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are always adding the class. You can check beforehand whether you want to remove it only or add it as well:

```
var $active_bg = $('.background-area.active_bg').removeClass("active_bg");
var $bg = $(this).parent('.background-area');

// Only add the class if the current background didn't have the class
if ($bg[0] !== $active_bg[0]) {
    $bg.addClass("active_bg");
}
```

The above code only allows one `.background-area` element to be "active". If there can be multiple, you can simplify your code to:

```
$(this).parent('.background-area').toggleClass("active_bg");
```

Comment: Thanks `Felix`, this helped me to solved this issue. Btw., I didn't know that is possible to use as a variable name in JS the `$` char.

Comment: What do you think `$` is in `$()`? ;) It's variable consisting of one character, `$`, which has a function as value.

Comment: I meant this: `var $bg` instead of `var bg`.

Comment: I know, but it's the same. Somewhere, jQuery is doing `var $ = jQuery;`.